# How often does Redis replicates through slaves

Tags: redis, database-replication

I want to know that if I setup the Redis replication as one master and 2 slaves on 3 remotely separated machines then how often does master and slave sync? I mean is it possible to configure that sync or replicate the database after every second or every write.

I want to use slaves only for replicating the database on separate machines.

Answer (score 3):

First, please read http://redis.io/topics/replication to understand how it works.

Redis is well adapted to replicate data on different machines (whatever the speed of the links). Some people even do it between data centers.

Replication is asynchronous, non-blocking for the master, and (as far as possible) immediate (i.e. after every write). If a slave is down or non-responsive, some data will be buffered on master side, until a certain point. You can tune the repl-backlog-size and repl-backlog-ttl parameters in the configuration to parameter this behavior.